# How do I update an int to string conversion in game?

Tags: c++

I am using SFML and C++ to make a little game where you try not to hit the walls and other objects I am adding later but I have a problem. I have a lives counter which works as I have a loop which stops when I get to zero lives. But the problem is the string conversion I did earlier doesn't update and uses the original number of lives I started with.
Here is code main.cpp

```
 #include <SFML/Audio.hpp>
 #include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
 #include <iomanip>
 #include <locale>
 #include <sstream>
 #include <string>

 using namespace std;

 #include "ResourcePath.hpp"
 #include "iostream"

int main(int, char const**)
{
int Lives = 5;
string textlives;          
ostringstream convert;   
convert << Lives;      
textlives = convert.str();

int x = 20;
int y = 20;
// Create the main window
sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "Dont hit it");

//Wall 1

sf::RectangleShape Wall1(sf::Vector2f(120, 50));
Wall1.setSize(sf::Vector2f(10, 1000));
Wall1.setPosition(0, 0);
Wall1.setFillColor(sf::Color::Blue);

//Wall 2
sf::RectangleShape Wall2(sf::Vector2f(120, 50));
Wall2.setSize(sf::Vector2f(1000, 10));
Wall2.setPosition(0, 0);
Wall2.setFillColor(sf::Color::Blue);
//Wall 3
sf::RectangleShape Wall3(sf::Vector2f(120, 50));
Wall3.setSize(sf::Vector2f(10, 1000));
Wall3.setPosition(790, 0);
Wall3.setFillColor(sf::Color::Blue);
//Wall 4
sf::RectangleShape Wall4(sf::Vector2f(120, 50));
Wall4.setSize(sf::Vector2f(1000, 10));
Wall4.setPosition(0, 590);
Wall4.setFillColor(sf::Color::Blue);

// Load a sprite to display
sf::CircleShape shape(25.f);
shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);
shape.setPosition(x, y);

// Create a graphical text to display
sf::Font font;
if (!font.loadFromFile(resourcePath() + "sansation.ttf")) {
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}


sf::Text text;
text.setFont(font);
text.setString("Unlucky you lost");
text.setCharacterSize(40);
text.setPosition(200, 300);
text.setStyle(sf::Text::Bold);

//textlives
sf::Text TextForLives;
TextForLives.setFont(font);
TextForLives.setString("Lives = " + textlives);
TextForLives.setCharacterSize(40);
TextForLives.setPosition(100, 100);
TextForLives.setStyle(sf::Text::Bold);

// Load a music to play
// sf::Music music;
//if (!music.openFromFile(resourcePath() + "nice_music.ogg")) {
//return EXIT_FAILURE;
// }

// Play the music
//music.play();

// Start the game loop
while (window.isOpen())
    {
        // Process events
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            // Close window: exit
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed) {
                window.close();
            }

            // Escape pressed: exit
            if (event.type == sf::Event::KeyPressed && event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Escape) {
                window.close();
            }
        }

    // Clear screen
    window.clear();
    if (Lives > 0) {
        if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::D))
        {
            // left key is pressed: move our character
            shape.move(0.1, 0);
        }
        if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::A))
        {
            // left key is pressed: move our character
            shape.move(-0.1, 0);
        }
        if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::W))
        {
            // left key is pressed: move our character
            shape.move(0, -0.1);
        }
        if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::S))
        {
            // left key is pressed: move our character
            shape.move(0., 0.1);
        }
        //Wall 1 collision
        if (shape.getGlobalBounds().intersects(Wall1.getGlobalBounds())) {
            cout << "Collided" << endl;
            shape.setPosition(20, 20);
            Lives = Lives - 1;
        }
        //Wall 2 collision
        if (shape.getGlobalBounds().intersects(Wall2.getGlobalBounds())) {
            cout << "Collided" << endl;
            shape.setPosition(20, 20);
            Lives = Lives - 1;
        }
        //Wall 3 collision
        if (shape.getGlobalBounds().intersects(Wall3.getGlobalBounds())) {
            cout << "Collided" << endl;
            shape.setPosition(20, 20);
            Lives = Lives - 1;
            ;
        }
        //Wall 4 collision
        if (shape.getGlobalBounds().intersects(Wall4.getGlobalBounds())) {
            cout << "Collided" << endl;
            shape.setPosition(20, 20);
            Lives = Lives - 1;
            ;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        window.draw(text);
    }

    // Update the window
    window.draw(shape);
    window.draw(Wall1);
    window.draw(Wall2);
    window.draw(Wall3);
    window.draw(Wall4);
    window.draw(TextForLives);
    window.display();
}

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: You just dump all your code on us?  How is shapes and fonts and music relevant to your question?? (MVCE)

Comment: You should strip the question down to only what is needed to reproduce and troubleshoot your issue.

Answer (score 1):

You're only converting your `Lives` to a string once at the beginning of the program, that's not correct.
You should re-convert every time you are going to draw it:

```
TextForLives.setString("Lives = " + std::to_string(Lives));
```

Comment: `std::to_string` only available with C++11

Comment: @Steephen Which is 5 years old, let's force people that can use it to use it.